# Unauthorized when calling getOneDriveActivityFileCounts

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I'm trying to access the OneDrive file activity report

```
/v1.0/reports/getOneDriveActivityFileCounts(period='D7')
```

but I always get the following error:

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": "S2SUnauthorized",
    "message": "Invalid scope claims/roles.",
    "innerError": {
      "request-id": "9bcd8f9c-7422-4721-9b48-eb49429f39c7",
      "date": "2018-11-06T10:40:05"
    }
  }
}
```

I checked [official Microsoft's documentation](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/reportroot_getonedriveactivityfilecounts) and it says that role `Reports.Read.All` is required but I still get the error even if I have it.

I can perfectly interact with other resources/segments of the API, so it isn't an authorization issue (I'm using Application Authorization with administrator permissions).

Looks like I cannot access any report... any ideas? thanks

Edit: adding the token (expired)

```
eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJub25jZSI6IkFRQUJBQUFBQUFDNXVuYTBFVUZnVElGOEVsYXh0V2pUUl9UZHVmVVhQYXRBa2J4NE9CbDFCd0VYV1hGRWMtc1hrZXRncV9CM240LWY4c1AtV3piUFhMWWlhU0ZlYUJyOWVWRUhlN05KQUJLSmZyMnFuWGNDZGlBQSIsImFsZyI6IlJTMjU2IiwieDV0Ijoid1VMbVlmc3FkUXVXdFZfLWh4VnRESkpaTTRRIiwia2lkIjoid1VMbVlmc3FkUXVXdFZfLWh4VnRESkpaTTRRIn0.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.KF1i203xJ9nCXeminHCSrjuYjSuFzgQ9aJK-XkvTxXQLUm66qYBotUmwQU5F8GmLMAB2lXwYq-ZNNvGvLY8IvjtVKk0VWqfz5QKCK4LSjZKAo1hTtdNGOGOHmn5uPgl7_iAxf8qBOtnVI1-yh8GM8QaxBRq48LXNRvz4punH2ItdGdKDSgOevDP75umRmz7gTJHY1c_PDipKiMBrxJKJSFp3fusraX981yCS0vYg2hi2djNy5Pj314a99wpre6f0L6HyEWmFLY4OGpSNFFn1H_Hu5iaFXn4b6BtpQN3NOhbsVwrfLq7qrOkJ4GkvOfU3O60dzPUeUWRSR13SenCbSQ
```

Comment: There isn't a lot do go on here. Please add the actual token you're receiving to your question.

Comment: is it ok if I give you an expired token? isn't the request-id enough? If you need a working token, I could provide one if you write to ivan.sanzcarasa@intive.com from an official Microsoft address. Thanks a lot btw

Comment: Expired is fine. I just need to decode it and see what scopes are actually being applied.

Comment: perfect. This is a token from yesterday: https://pastebin.com/CK3pRNTt

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on the token you provided, you are not receiving `Reports.Read.All` permission. This is the decoded token:

```json
{
  "typ": "JWT",
  "nonce": "AQABAAAAAAC5una0EUFgTIF8ElaxtWjTR_TdufUXPatAkbx4OBl1BwEXWXFEc-sXketgq_B3n4-f8sP-WzbPXLYiaSFeaBr9eVEHe7NJABKJfr2qnXcCdiAA",
  "alg": "RS256",
  "x5t": "wULmYfsqdQuWtV_-hxVtDJJZM4Q",
  "kid": "wULmYfsqdQuWtV_-hxVtDJJZM4Q"
}.{
  "aud": "https://graph.microsoft.com",
  "iss": "https://sts.windows.net/00a83132-4221-4698-a787-6d679d557a90/",
  "iat": 1541498908,
  "nbf": 1541498908,
  "exp": 1541502808,
  "aio": "42RgYFi9rl/pqqH+uomiicUJt/1uAgA=",
  "app_displayname": "Dante (Intive.com)",
  "appid": "2d6f432b-1c10-490c-9490-da7956893e5b",
  "appidacr": "1",
  "e_exp": 262800,
  "idp": "https://sts.windows.net/00a83132-4221-4698-a787-6d679d557a90/",
  "oid": "e5777cf4-4131-4021-9e60-e03d832f9cf1",
  "roles": [
    "People.Read.All",
    "Group.Read.All",
    "EduAdministration.Read.All",
    "Files.ReadWrite.All",
    "Directory.Read.All",
    "User.Read.All",
    "Files.Read.All"
  ],
  "sub": "e5777cf4-4131-4021-9e60-e03d832f9cf1",
  "tid": "00a83132-4221-4698-a787-6d679d557a90",
  "uti": "rTqRvtJ08ECCanOh7FMWAA",
  "ver": "1.0",
  "xms_tcdt": 1442403292
}.[Signature]
```

Note that it only includes the following roles (aka scopes):

- `People.Read.All`
- `Group.Read.All`
- `EduAdministration.Read.All`
- `Files.ReadWrite.All`
- `Directory.Read.All`
- `User.Read.All`
- `Files.Read.All`

In order to access `/getOneDriveActivityFileCounts`, you need to add `Reports.Read.All` to your application's registration.

It is also important to note that simply adding it to the registration will *not* provide that permission to the application. You must also receive [Administrative Consent](https://massivescale.com/microsoft-v2-endpoint-admin-consent/) before the requested scopes can be activated. Whenever you add/drop a scope from the registration, *you must repeat the Admin Consent process*.

Comment: sounds like this is the issue (the role was added after administrative consent). I'll check tomorrow, thanks a lot!